# when i rotate this shape with (-43), then text going to zig zag

Tags: css, css-shapes

when i rotate this shape with `rotate(-43deg)`, then text going to zig zag. 
Can it possible the text can be align? 
Please help me.
Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/yxy1rwqk/2/

```css
.rotate {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #961214;
  border-left: 19px solid transparent;
  border-right: 21px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 123px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-43deg) translate(1px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-43deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-43deg) translate(0);
  -o-transform: rotate(-43deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-43deg);
  transition: all 0.05s ease-in 0.1s;
  padding: 0px 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">Leading Supplier</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome. Is this an issue in a specific browser?

Comment: Please: post your actual code, tell us what browser you use, possibly add a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox, too.

Comment: Is it better with 45°, the exact half of 90° the right angle?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Not sure if this has been addressed in recent versions of Chrome. I am on GC25 (don't ask why :P) and I can see the issue. I have come across this earlier also but never had a solution. [This](http://i.imgur.com/JA3le9y.png) is what I see.

Comment: @Harry Yes, this was and old issue with Chrome. I believe it could be solved adding a perspective to the element